# Derivatives of matrices

Tags: self-study, bayesian, multivariate-normal-distribution, variational-bayes

Consider multiple response data from a matrix normal distribution $Y_{n\times m}\sim\text{Normal}(\mathbf{M},\mathbf{U},\mathbf{V})$, where $\mathbf{U}=\mathbf{I}_n$ is the variance among rows and $\mathbf{V}$ is the $m\times m$ variance across columns (assumed symmetric and positive-definite). $\mathbf{Y}$ can be also represented as $ \mathbf{y}=\text{vec}(\mathbf{Y}) \sim \text{Normal}(\mathbf{m}=\text{vec}(\mathbf{M}),\mathbf{I}_n\otimes\mathbf{V})$ such that the corresponding log-likelihood is
$$ f(\mathbf{y}|\mathbf{V},\mathbf{m}) = -\dfrac{nm}{2}\log(2\pi)-\dfrac{1}{2}\log|\mathbf{I}_n\otimes\mathbf{V}|-\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{m})^{\prime}(\mathbf{I}_n\otimes\mathbf{V})^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{m}).$$

Assuming the parameterization $\mathbf{V}=\mathbf{LDL}^{\prime}$, where $\mathbf{L}$ is a lower triangular matrix with ones on the diagonal, and $\mathbf{D}$ is a diagonal matrix with strictly positive elements, in the simplest case with $m=2$ we have
$$\mathbf{V} = \left[\begin{array}{cc}V_{11} & V_{12}\\
                                V_{12} & V_{22}
\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\
                                L_{12} & 1
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}D_{11} & 0\\
                                0 & D_{22}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & L_{12}\\
                                0 & 1
\end{array}\right].$$
I would like to estimate $\mathbf{V}$ (i.e., $L_{12}$, $D_{11}$, and $D_{22}$) using a variational bayes approach for which a potential choice of priors could be
\begin{equation}
L_{12}\sim \text{Normal}(0, c),\\
log(D_{ii})\sim \text{Normal}(0, b),\;i=1,2
\end{equation}

with $c$ and $b$ constants. For approaches like gradient descent I will need the gradient of the log-posterior
\begin{equation}
f(L_{12}, D_{11}, D_{22}|\mathbf{y}) = -\dfrac{nm}{2}\log(2\pi)-\dfrac{1}{2}\log|\mathbf{I}_n\otimes\mathbf{LDL}^{\prime}|-\dfrac{1}{2}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{m})^{\prime}(\mathbf{I}_n\otimes\mathbf{LDL}^{\prime})^{-1}(\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{m}) \\
-\dfrac{1}{2}\log(2\pi c) -\dfrac{L_{12}^2}{2c} -\log(2\pi b)-\sum_{i=1}^2\dfrac{D_{ii}^2}{2b}
\end{equation}

with respect to $L_{12}$, $D_{11}$, and $D_{22}$. While I am familiar with the use of the chain rule and the identities $\dfrac{\partial\log|\mathbf{X}|}{\partial\mathbf{X}}=2\mathbf{X}^{-1}-\text{diag}(\mathbf{X})$ and $\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{X}^{-1}}{\partial\mathbf{X}}=-\mathbf{X}^{-1}\dfrac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial\mathbf{X}}\mathbf{X}^{-1}$, I am having trouble figuring those for the LDL parameterization and the Kronecker product. I'd appreciate some references or guidance on how to explicitly calculate them. Thanks.

Comment: My first (and second) look would be at https://www.wiley-vch.de/de/fachgebiete/mathematik-und-statistik/matrix-differential-calculus-with-applications-in-statistics-and-econometrics-978-1-119-54120-2